# git: get *new* contributors (authors) list in release/tag

Tags: git, git-log

I'm preparing changelog for a release and doing some statistic.

It's quite easy to list contributors from previous release:

```
git shortlog -s -e -n TAG..
```

reviewers:

```
git log TAG.. | grep -Ei '(reviewed|acked)-by:' |sed 's/.*by: //' | sort | uniq -c | sort -n -r
```

committers:

```
git shortlog -s -e -n -c TAG..
```

But how to list new contributors (authors) since `TAG` (e.g. those who haven't been committing before `TAG`)?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming you can use `bash`, there are at least two ways:

```sh
#!/bin/bash

set -e

OLD_COMMIT="$1"
NEW_COMMIT="$2"
if test -z "$OLD_COMMIT" || test -z "$NEW_COMMIT"; then
    echo 'fatal: must provide OLD_COMMIT and NEW_COMMIT commits' >&2
    exit 1
fi
shift 2
```

The first, using declarative arrays introduced back in bash 4 (emulates right outer join in imperative fashion):

```sh
declare -A OLD_AUTHORS
while read -r OLD_AUTHOR; do
    OLD_AUTHORS["$OLD_AUTHOR"]=1
done < <(git log --pretty=format:%aN "$OLD_COMMIT")

declare -A NEW_AUTHORS
while read -r NEW_AUTHOR; do
    if test -z ${OLD_AUTHORS["$NEW_AUTHOR"]}; then
        NEW_AUTHORS["$NEW_AUTHOR"]=1
    fi
done < <(git log --pretty=format:%aN "$OLD_COMMIT"~1.."$NEW_COMMIT")

for NEW_AUTHOR in "${!NEW_AUTHORS[@]}"; do
    echo "$NEW_AUTHOR"
done | sort
```

Or, the second, using pipes and somewhat more declarative way:

```sh
diff \
    <(git log --pretty=format:%aN "$OLD_COMMIT" | sort | uniq) \
    <(git log --pretty=format:%aN "$OLD_COMMIT"~1.."$NEW_COMMIT" | sort | uniq) \
    | grep '^> ' \
    | cut -c 3-
```

Both of the above solutions can process the following history (`git log --pretty=format:'%h %d% aN'`):

```
c3d766e  (tag: v2) Keith
cffddc6  New John
ee3cc52  Dan
c307f13  (tag: v1) New John
ae3c4a3  New John
9ed948e  Old John
7eb548a  Old John
```

like this (`show-new-authors.sh v1 v2`):

```
Dan
Keith
```

Comment: Thanks a lot! I hoped there would be some one liner :). Ad `bash`: I'd transform it to posix shell (no bashisms like arrays), to be able to use it in `busybox sh` (`ash` implementation, which is used in Alpine Linux), but that's a minor detail.

Comment: @pevik You didn't mention that in your question. I don't usually think of bashisms since I use bash only, but it seems that the second "4-liner" is also a [bashism](https://askubuntu.com/a/229450). In your case, I assume, temporary files should be used?

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it's valid (thus I marked it so). My concern why I asked this question was to find if there is some git upstream solution similar to `git shortlog`. It's not difficult to write a custom script to solve this, but I'm thinking to contribute to git upstream this functionality into `git shortlog`.

Comment: Probably not surprising, but your second solution using pipes takes less than half as long to execute as the first solution. 0:29 vs. 1:04 for 100 iterations with git 2.37.2 and bash 5.2.2.